# How do I clear text after HTML form is submitted in PHP on the same page

Tags: php, html

I want to clear or hide the HTML text (HTML form) when the PHP code is executed.

I just want to show **`if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {}`**.
The following is my code called in index.php.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="formku">
        <legend><b>Input Score (0 - 4)</b></legend>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <legend><span class="number">1</span>N1 : </legend>
        <input required type="text" name="n1" />  
        S1 : 
        <input required type="text" name="s1" /> <br/>
        <legend><span class="number">2</span>N2 : </legend>
        <input required type="text" name="n2" /> 
        S2 : 
        <input required type="text" name="s2" /> <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Count"/>
    </form>
    <hr>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $vn1 = $_POST['n1'];
    $vn2 = $_POST['n2'];
    echo '<h2>Result</h2>';
    echo 'Final score N1 = ' . $vn1 * $vs1 . '<br>';
    echo 'Final score N2 = ' . $vn2 * $vs2 . '<br>';
    $tn = ($vn1 * $vs1) + ($vn2 * $vs2);
    $ts = $vs1 + $vs2;
    $ip = $tn / $ts;
    echo 'IP Value: ' . $ip;
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'You got: ';
    if ($ip >= 4)
        echo 'A';
    else if ($ip >= 3)
        echo 'B';
    else if ($ip >= 2)
        echo 'C';
    else if ($ip >= 1)
        echo 'D';
    else
        echo 'E';
}
?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the code here. We love code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use else condition:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //show the message of submit
    $vn1 = $_POST['n1'];
    $vn2 = $_POST['n2'];
    ....
} else {
    //show the form data
?>
    <form ...>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the if statement you can echo the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementsByClassName('formku')[0].display = "none";
</script>
```